# Bootstrap Jumbotron Background Image Height issue

Tags: html, image, twitter-bootstrap, background, height

I'm trying to display an image (1920x800px) as a background in the jumbotron.

HTML:

```
<div class="jumbotron bg">
  <div class="container">
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.bg {
  background: url('../images/ac-unity.jpg');
  background-size: cover;
}

.jumbotron {
padding: 30px 15px;
margin-bottom: 30px;
color: inherit;
}

.container {
  padding-right: 15px;
  padding-left: 15px;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
}
```

As seen [here](http://dws.cmi.hanze.nl/322796/project/index.php) (hosted on my school server), the height of the image is not fully displayed, because of the content of the container. By assigning a height to .bg I get the full image, but the image isn't responsive anymore. How can I make sure that the jumbotron will display the full height of the image but still be responsive for mobile?

Regards

Comment: Apply the background to the `body` instead of a `div`.

Comment: as APAD1 wrote: body { background: url('../images/ac-unity.jpg'); }

Comment: Are you trying to make the background always 100% width, or 100% height of its parent?

Comment: Well, I don't want to have other content on the image except the jumbotron, so I thought it'd be best to put it somewhere around the jumbotron. I was wondering if it was possible for the jumbotron or container to sow the whole image, regardless of the header content.

Answer (score 0):

Try putting the jumbotron within a row and container:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="jumbotron bg">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I want the jumbotron to fill the whole page, so the container has to be inside the jumbotron. Putting it in a row doesn't do anything different.